# meteor.js (server side): console.log won't work outside of main.ts

Tags: logging, meteor, server

So I'm getting some pretty weird errors and so I'm adding a lot of logging, but none of my logs appear.

I mean, if I add logs in the entrypoint file of the server (main.ts) logs do appear.

If I call a function defined in another file, that logs something, it doesn't log it.

Why???

Comment: how are we supposed to help with that without seeing your code? Which file are you putting the `console.log` in? Are you sure it executes?

Comment: Agree with @ChristianFritz, show us the files. It's likely that your file isn't getting imported